# How to read this Function/Relation? One-to-One Proof? (Discrete Mathematics)

Tags: functions, relations, proof-explanation

Define function J : Q×Q → R by the rule J(r, s) = r+
sqrt(2)s for all (r, s) ∈ Q×Q

I have no real idea how to read this. My thoughts are:
For every pair of rationals in QxQ, or the pair of any two rationals, r and s, J = the function listed above.

Now, typical strategy for 1-1 is to make r1, s1, r2, s2, and see if you can derive an equality; now, I've decided that this function is not 1-1, but I'm not exactly sure how to show a counter example being as sqrt(2) doesn't have a value I can really work with....

Either way, I'm expected to give a counterexample and I don't entirely know where to start.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you mean  r+√2*s which is sum of r and product √2s?

Comment: Yes. r + sqrt(2)*s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function actually *is* one-to-one.

A function $f$ is $1-1$ if whenever $f(y) = f(z)$, it follows that $y = z$.  Ok, so let's look at $J(r_{1}, r_{2})$ and $J(s_{1}, s_{2})$.  Suppose they are equal.  We want to show $(r_{1}, r_{2}) = (s_{1},s_{2})$.

Well, if $J(r_{1}, r_{2}) = J(s_{1}, s_{2})$, then $r_{1} + \sqrt{2}r_{2} = s_{1} + \sqrt{2}s_{2}$.  That means $$r_{1} - s_{1} + \sqrt{2}(r_{2} - s_{2}) = 0 \tag{1}.$$  Since $r_{1}, r_{2}, s_{1}, s_{2}$ are rational numbers, the *only way* this can happen is if $r_{1} = s_{1}$ and $r_{2} = s_{2}$.

To see why this is, note that if $r_{1} \neq s_{1}$ and $r_{2} \neq s_{2}$, then $r_{1} - s_{1} \neq 0$ and $r_{2} - s_{2} \neq 0$.

By (1), we then get $\sqrt{2} = \dfrac{r_{1} - s_{1}}{r_{2}-s_{2}}$.  But each piece of the right hand side is rational, so the whole right hand side is rational, while the left hand side is irrational!  Contradiction!  Thus, the differences *have* to equal $0$, and so $(r_{1}, r_{2}) = (s_{1}, s_{2})$.

Comment: This seems to solve the problem. I'm so bad at this, I read my instruction materials and still can't see basic stuff :(

Comment: @smitty_werbermanjensen No worries, it's probably a lot of pressure to be #1. :D

Comment: One other question - I understand proving onto in a single parameter function, how would I do it in a multiparameter? Do I show each parameter isolated in terms of the other and y?

Comment: @smitty_werbermanjensen Are you still talking about the same function?  In general, if you want to prove a function $f : X \to Y$ is *onto*, you need to show for each $y$ in $Y$, we can find an $x \in X$ with $f(x) = y$.  In some cases, you can write $y = f(x)$ and solve for $x$...

Comment: I am still speaking of the same function detailed originally. Sorry for the late response! How do I prove it's onto with multiple parameters? Or, if it isn't onto, that's fine. I just don't know how to prove one or the other in this case. My text doesn't help much since it just deals with "normal" stuff like f(x).

Comment: If you want to prove $J$ is onto, you need to show for each real number $r \in \Bbb R$, we can find rational numbers $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ so that $q_{1} + \sqrt{2}q_{2} = r$.  But actually, I don't think $J$ is onto, anyway.  $\sqrt{5}$ is a real number that doesn't have anything being mapped to it.  To see why, suppose that we *did* have rational numbers $q_{1}, q_{2}$ with $q_{1} + q_{2}\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{5}$...

Comment: ...Then squaring both sides would give that $q_{1}^{2} + 2q_{1}q_{2}\sqrt{2} + 2q_{2}^{2} = 5$, which would mean $\sqrt{2} = \frac{5 - 2q_{2}^{2} - q_{1}^{2}}{2q_{1}q_{2}}$.  But this is a contradiction since the LHS is irrational and the RHS is rational.  So, $J$ is not onto since no element of the form $q_{1} + q_{2}\sqrt{2}$ can equal $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: How do you people learn this T_T

I can't seem to get it and I have no idea what resources to consult.... it's depressing.

Comment: @smitty_werbermanjensen I was where you are now once.  I didn't learn what I know now over night, but only with practice.  The problem you just worked on was very good practice (if you truly understand it).  If you want more practice proving functions are 1-1 and onto, here are some relatively easy functions to work with: $f(x) = x$,  $g(x) = 3x + 5$, and  $h(x) = x^{2}$.

Comment: @smitty_werbermanjensen $f$ and $g$ are both one-to-one and onto, which is something you should prove.  $h$ is neither one-to-one nor onto, so you'll have to explain why.

Comment: One last question, since you've been very helpful: How would I read this function: (h◦g)◦f(x)?

Comment: @smitty_werbermanjensen The circle is another notation for composition.  So $(h \circ g)(x)$ means $h(g(x))$.  Composition is associative, so the parentheses don't matter.  What I mean is, $h \circ g \circ f = (h \circ g)\circ f = h \circ (g \circ f)$.  In your case, $((h\circ g)\circ f)$ is just the same as $h \circ g \circ f$ which is $h(g(f(x))$.